# Objective-C Expected Identifier - simple syntax debugging problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I need help debugging this error `Expected Identifier`. The code is -

```
+(NSString *)dayOfWeek {
    NSDate *day = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:day];
    day = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    NSLog(@"The DAY OF THE WEEK is -- %@", day);
    NSArray *daysOfTheWeek = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sunday", @"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday", @"Thursday", @"Friday", @"Saturday", nil];

    NSString *dayName = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[daysOfTheWeek objectAtIndex:[[components weekday]-1]]]];
    return dayName;
}
```

I get the error marker at `-1]`, underneath the `]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this line:

```
NSString *dayName = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[daysOfTheWeek objectAtIndex:[[components weekday]-1]]]];
```

should look like this:

```
NSString *dayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[daysOfTheWeek objectAtIndex:[components weekday]-1]];
```

I changed initWithFormat due to a compiler warning. You are not subsituting anything so initWithString should suffice for the beginning.

Comment: "I changed initWithFormat due to a compiler warning." It's actually a pretty serious bug to pass a raw string to a function that accepts a format string. Obvious here there were a fixed set of inputs, but if one of those days happened to be @"Mond%@y", the program would crash.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *dayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[daysOfTheWeek objectAtIndex:[components weekday]-1]];
```

**EDIT:** Just like Nick Weaver pointed out you should probably use `initWithString:`:

```
NSString *dayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[daysOfTheWeek objectAtIndex:[components weekday]-1]];
```

**EDIT 2:** Not sure why you need to create a new string. Isn't the following sufficient?

```
NSString *dayName = [daysOfTheWeek objectAtIndex:[components weekday]-1];
```

**Note:** I think the real issue here is that you don't really know what brackets are used for.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
NSString *dayName = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[daysOfTheWeek objectAtIndex:[[components weekday]-1]]]];
```

Use

```
NSString *dayName = [daysOfTheWeek objectAtIndex:[components weekday]-1];
```

Comment: +1 He has an array of strings, so why does he need to create a new one?

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSString *)dayOfWeek {
    NSDate *day = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:day];
    day = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    NSLog(@"The DAY OF THE WEEK is -- %@", day);
    NSArray *daysOfTheWeek = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sunday", @"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday", @"Thursday", @"Friday", @"Saturday", nil];
    NSString *dayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[daysOfTheWeek objectAtIndex:[components weekday] - 1 ]];
    return dayName;
}
```

will work :)